# Can software keep my laptop from charging?

Tags: laptop, debian, power-supply, battery, power

I have a Lenovo S540 with debian testing (stretch) set up. A couple of days ago I noticed that the battery is not charging even when it's plugged in. Of course this could be a broken power cord of loading circuit. Here is why I suspect it might be a software failure:

1. I did a major update of >200 packages on that day, which might have messed things up. Although I'm not quite sure, if the problem appeared right after the update.
2. It must have happened very abruptly, since it worked fine a couple of days earlier and then stopped without me doing anything crazy to the cable. Is it likely for the circuitry to break on its own just like that? The computer is about 1-2 years old.
3. Usually when the cable is broken one can wiggle and bend it in certain ways to 'fix' the loose contact. Nothing like this works for me.

I will test my charger on another computer later today and will post an update with the results as soon as I can. Unfortunately the laptop has since lost all of it's charge and doesn't turn on even when it's plugged in. Also the battery is built in so I cannot easily remove it. 
I tried holding the power button for some time to reset the computer but that didn't do anything.

Is it possible that this might be software-related or should I look into the hardware?

Comment: It seems it's hardware. It can be the battery  or its charge sensor, as well as the charger. Start to test the charger. If it works it is inside the computer and it is more expensive :(. Good luck.

Comment: I was mislead for it was indeed a hardware issue. I think the question should be deleted, as it doesn't really help anyone. Thanks for your answers!

Comment: Hi, please [edit] your post or (better) write your own answer,  writing also which hardware problem it was and how you discover (what failed attempt too) ...  it can help. (Btw you can select even a answer different from your  to give 15 points  to the ones that helped you)...

Comment: I have picked the answer that stated it is likely a hardware failure, yet also answered the initial question. In the end it was really just the box in the cable that was fried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost certainly a hardware issue in your case,

but to answer the title question, yes, software can stop your laptop from charging, I think lenovo laptops actually have a built in software to optimize battery life by cutting off the charge at 60%

Answer (score 0):

The power supply provided with your laptop is made to supply enough power to keep the battery level.

It might not be the case of third party, aging or defective power supplies.

It will all depend on its electrical characteristics (max output power, intensity, ...) and the overall power consumption of your laptop components.

If you want to test your power supply, be sure to test it in the same conditions (same laptop, same activity).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running Lenovo System Update?

Lenovos/Thinkpads come with a utility where you can specify charging thresholds, eg "don't charge battery if its 90% full."  I think it was called Power Manager and it would sit in the taskbar near the clock.  Perhaps something went funky with that, or the drivers it uses.

Comment: I no longer have the original operating system installed. Would I find this PowerManager in the Bios? Also the computer doesn't turn on.

Comment: Sorry I just realized you were running Linux!  Will the laptop turn on with the battery removed while on AC?

Comment: I have not yet removed the battery as it is built in. It doesn't work when plugged in.

Comment: Seems like a hardware issue. You can use a multimeter to see if any voltage is coming from the adapter. Otherwise it could be a loose charging port. Worst case would be the charging circuit on the board is bad, or whatever Lenovo uses in that model.